# Query performance of T-SQL in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization, database-performance

I have two ad-hoc query in SQL Server like below,

```
select * 
from Product(nolock) 
where id = '12345' and name = 'ABC';

select * 
from Product(nolock) 
where name = 'ABC' and id = '12345';
```

We have clustered index on id column and no index on name column. Which query will be faster? And why?

Comment: **Bad Habits to kick**: [putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: You can turn on the execution plan in SSMS and see for yourself.

Comment: And if you need to use a hint (and understand the consequences), then AT LEAST use the current syntax and NOT the deprecated syntax.

Comment: Presumably column id is numeric - so why do you use string constants and force an implicit conversion?

Answer (score 0):

The performance **will be the same**.

The SQL Server query optimizer is **smart enough** to see that the conditions are the same - just in different order.

Ordering of the conditions in the `WHERE` clause isn't relevant.

SQL Server will select foremost by the `id`, and then in a second step sequentially by `name`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it is irrelevant:

[I created a products table with primary key clustered on ID and replicated your test case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BP2by.png)

Enabling execution plan will give you the answer :)

Code for the test:

```
drop table if exists products
Create table products
(
id int primary key clustered,
Value1 float
)

;with randowvalues
    as(
       select 1 id, CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*100 as varchar(100)) randomnumber
       --select 1 id, RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*100 randomnumber
        union  all
        select id + 1, CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*100 as varchar(100))  randomnumber
        
        from randowvalues
        where 
          id < 1000
      )
 
 
insert into products
select *
from randowvalues
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)

select *
from products
where id = 9 and value1 = 75.6648

select *
from products
where  value1 = 75.6648 and id = 9
```